# Exchange CMDLETs Disappeared

Tags: powershell

Please can you help me.

I am running powershell version:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1682
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1682
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Apparently M$ have recently retired several cmdlets from ExchangeOnline/ExchangeOnlineManagement recently, but I didn't think that cmdlets like Get-SafeAttachmentsPolicy, Get-Safe-LinksPolicy etc would also have been retired.

```
Get-SafeAttachmentPolicy : The term 'Get-SafeAttachmentPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-SafeAttachmentPolicy
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-SafeAttachmentPolicy:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Here is a list of the installed modules and their versions:

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Binary     2.0.2.149  AzureADPreview                      {Add-AzureADAdministrativeUnitMember, Add-AzureADApplicationOwner, Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy, Add-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner...}
Script     2.0.5      ExchangeOnlineManagement            {Get-EXOCasMailbox, Get-EXOMailbox, Get-EXOMailboxFolderPermission, Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics...}
Script     1.9.6      Microsoft.Graph.Authentication      {Add-MgEnvironment, Connect-MgGraph, Disconnect-MgGraph, Get-MgContext...}
Script     1.9.6      Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Directo... {Confirm-MgContactMemberGroup, Confirm-MgContactMemberObject, Confirm-MgContractMemberGroup, Confirm-MgContractMemberObject...}
Script     1.9.6      Microsoft.Graph.Identity.SignIns    {Get-MgDataPolicyOperation, Get-MgIdentityConditionalAccessNamedLocation, Get-MgIdentityConditionalAccessPolicy, Get-MgIdentityProvider...}
Binary     6.1907.1.0 Microsoft.Graph.Intune              {Connect-MSGraph, Get-DeviceAppManagement, Get-DeviceAppManagement_AndroidManagedAppProtections, Get-DeviceAppManagement_AndroidManagedAppProtections_Apps...}
Script     1.9.6      Microsoft.Graph.Security            {Get-MgSecurityAlert, Get-MgSecuritySecureScore, Get-MgSecuritySecureScoreControlProfile, New-MgSecurityAlert...}
Binary     16.0.22... Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powe... {Add-SPOGeoAdministrator, Add-SPOHubSiteAssociation, Add-SPOHubToHubAssociation, Add-SPOListDesign...}
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Script     4.3.0      MicrosoftTeams                      {Add-TeamChannelUser, Add-TeamUser, Connect-MicrosoftTeams, Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams...}
Manifest   1.1.183.66 MSOnline                            {Add-MsolAdministrativeUnitMember, Add-MsolForeignGroupToRole, Add-MsolGroupMember, Add-MsolRoleMember...}
Script     2.0.0      PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler...}
Script     1.0        tmp_i2it3aea.rt1                    {Add-ComplianceCaseMember, Add-eDiscoveryCaseAdmin, Add-RoleGroupMember, Delete-QuarantineMessage...}
Script     1.0        tmp_wjisgfad.jzu                    {Add-AvailabilityAddressSpace, Add-DistributionGroupMember, Add-MailboxFolderPermission, Add-MailboxLocation...}
```

Anyone got any idea where they have gone and, hopefully, how to get them back?

Yes, I have looked in the exported commands from the two session modules.

Thanks in advance
Liam

Comment: It might have to do with your permissions. Exchange CMDlets are imported through a remote connection when connecting to Exchange. If I have the incorrect PIM roles active in AzureAD I'm missing a lot of CMDlets (same is when I'm missing some of the exchange roles)

Comment: How did you get the list of those modules?